# Ruby looping program gives error

Tags: ruby

Here's what I wrote to check if a number is prime or not

```
print "Enter number : "
num = gets.chomp
i = 1
boo = true
while (i<num)
    if (i%num==0) 
        boo=true
    end
    i++
end

if (boo==true)
    puts (num+"is a prime number")
else
    puts (num+"is not a prime number")
end
```

This gives an error, how can I fix it?

The output from cmd prompt:

[image]

Comment: can you please post the text and not the picture? it's easier to read it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems:

- `++` operator doesn't exist in Ruby, you can use `+= 1` instead
- your `num` is a string, you can make it a number with `to_i` method, like `num.to_i`
- if the reminder of your number divided by a precedent number is zero you should set to false, not true
- if you start at 1 your number will result always prime

Anyway, in a more idiomatic Ruby you can write this code something like

```
print "Enter number : "
num = gets.chomp.to_i
prime = (2..num - 1).all? { |i| num % i != 0 }
if prime
  puts "#{num} is prime"
else
  puts "#{num} is not prime"
end
```

Comment: Or you could cheat a little and do: `require 'prime'; 13.prime? #=> true`

Comment: Thanks a lot! And yes, I want to learn as many languages as I can! :D :)